# define nominal variable for multivariate analysis

Tags: r, variables, linear-regression, categorical-data

In my database I have treatment codes and I can calculate healthcare activity rates. I would like to perform a multivariate analysis to see for which treatment type patients are most likely to receive echo and/or mri.

The treatments all have several healthcare codes (character)

```
anthracyclines = c("55", "68", "402")
trastuzumab = c("200", "201", "202")
alkylatingagents = c("106", "208", "300", "610")
```

now I would like to make one variable for treatments.
I defined it like this:

```
treatments = as.factor(c(anthracyclines, trastuzumab, alkylatingagents))
```

But R still defines it as a factor with 10 levels, referring to the original codes.
How should I code it to change it into 3 levels?

The models should eventually look like this:
With the % of imaging as continuous variable.

```
model.im = lm(imaging ~ as.factor(treatments) + Age)
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume a treatment vector like you said:

```
treatments = c(anthracyclines, trastuzumab, alkylatingagents)
```

If the treatments and imaging are in this order of 3 anthracyclines, 3 trastuzumab and 4 alkalingagents, you can simply write

```
Treatment = rep(c("anthracyclines","trastuzumab","alkylatingagents"),times=c(3,3,4))
lm(imaging ~ Treatments + Age)
```

If not, try making a list to map them

```
drug2cat = rep(c("anthracyclines","trastuzumab","alkylatingagents"),
times=c(length(anthracyclines),length(trastuzumab),length(alkylatingagents))
)
names(drug2cat) = c(anthracyclines, trastuzumab, alkylatingagents)
Treatments = drug2cat[treatments]
lm(imaging ~ Treatments + Age)
```